# Storing values from HTML Collection in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, coldfusion

I'm new to all this and I really need help.  I've been on this for hours now.
I have these checkboxes.  I'm using a cfoutput to generate them and giving them each the value of SID from the query.

```
<cfoutput query="getvalues">
<div><input type="checkbox" name="chk" id=#getvalues.SID# value=#getvalues.SID# class="chkbxs">
</cfoutput>
<input type="button" name="PrintSelected" value="Print Selected" onclick="printTextArea()">
```

The only thing I want to do is get the values of these checkboxes and store them in an array.  getElementsByClassName returns an html collection.  I've been told I need to loop over the html collection and then store the values in a new array which is what I attempted below but this isn't working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function printTextArea() {
    var myList = document.getElementsByClassName("chkbxs");
    var newList = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
    newList.push(myList[i].value); 
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < newList.length j++)
    {
    alert (newList[j]);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting anything in the console. I don't see the javascript function getting called.

Comment: I've edited the question, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: `newList[i] = console.log(myList[i].value);` -> `newList.push(myList[i].value);` ([`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push))

Comment: I tried this change and am still not getting any alerts.  Any other ideas that might be keeping this from running?  (edited the question to reflect the change)

Comment: Your solution worked as well after Teemoh pointed out the missing semicolon.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you setting the array items to `console.log(myList[i].value);`?

`console.log()` just returns `undefined`.

Just change the line to following:

```
 newList[i] = myList[i].value;
```

Comment: I had it set that way because I honestly don't know what I'm doing here.  I'm trying anything at this point to get it to run.  I tried your change and it's still not working.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Try to log the nodelist you get from getElementsByClassName: console.log(myList); Then you can check if the input element is correctly selected.

Comment: You also forgot a semicolon in the second for-loop (after "j < newList.length").

Comment: You sir, are a god.  It was just the semicolon.  It's working now.  Thank you.